# Selenium - Click option from dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to acess this page where I need to select a option from a dropdown menu before I type into the search bar and proceed.

The button's HTML is

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span>PT</span> <button>
```

for the main button that opens the dropdown menu.

I can click this button, that opens the dropdown menu, with seleniun in python with

```
select = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@data-toggle='dropdown']") ### XPATH = .//button[@data-toggle='dropdown']; select.click();
```

and the dropdown menu opens but then i cant select the option that i want.

When the dropdown menu is open, the HTML code is

```
<div class="dropdown-menu show" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(-1px, 26px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">  </div>
```

and every option is the following

```
1:<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-region="pt1">PT1</a>

2:<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-region="pt2">PT2</a>

3:<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-region="pt3">PT3</a>
```

Can someone help me, please? I can't understand why i cant select/click the option that i want (option3).

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: _but then i cant select the option that i want._ we dont know what options you want to select, and what options drop down consist. Please read [mcve] and edit your question properly.provide code you tried. currently very little information

Comment: @JoaoNuno Instead of the handcrafted HTML, update the question with the text based actual HTML.